# php adjacency list to selectbox

Tags: php, adjacency-list

I have an array and would like to generate the select box. I know it should use recursion but don't know how it works. 
I have an example of code for generating nested list but now I'm looking for the way to build something like below:

```
<select>
  <option value="1">Category1</option>
  <option value="4">::SubCategory2</option>
  <option value="2">::SubCategory1</option>
  <option value="3">::::SubSubCategory</option>
</select>
```

How can I do this?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Category1
            [parent] => 0
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                            [name] => SubCategory2
                            [parent] => 1
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [name] => SubCategory1
                            [parent] => 1
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 3
                                            [name] => SubSubCategory
                                            [parent] => 2
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )
)

function GenerateSet($nav, $tabs = "") {
        $html = !strlen($tabs) ? 
                "\n".$tabs.'<ul class="categories">'."\n" : 
                "\n".$tabs.'<ul>'."\n";

        foreach($nav as $page) {

            $html .= $tabs."    ".'<li id="cat-'.$page['id'].'">';
            $html .= ' <a href="#">
                                <span class="linker">
                                    <span class="title">'.$page['name'].'</span>
                                </span>
                            </a>';

            if(isset($page['children'][0])) {
                $html .= $this->GenerateSet($page['children'], $tabs."        ");
            }
            $html .= '</li>'."\n";
        }
        $html .= $tabs.'</ul>'."\n";

        return $html;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. If the current item has children, then incrase the level, and show it by the same function, else, decrase the level.

```
$array = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'Cat 1',
        'children' => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'Subcat 1'
            )
        )
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Cat 2',
        'children' => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'Sub2',
                'children' => array(
                    array(
                        'name' => 'Sub3'
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ),
);

echo showTree($array);

function showTree($items, $level = 0) {
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        echo str_repeat(":", $level * 2) . $item['name'] . "<br />";
        if (!empty($item['children'])) {
            $level++;
            showTree($item['children'], $level);
        }
        if ($level > 0) {
            $level--;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
<?php
$your_array = array(
                '0' => array(
                        'id' => 1,
                        'name' => 'Category1',
                        'parent' => 0,
                        'children' => array
                            (
                                '0' => array
                                    (
                                        'id' => 4,
                                        'name' => 'SubCategory2',
                                        'parent' => 1,
                                        'children' => array
                                            (
                                            )

                                    ),

                                '1' => array
                                    (
                                        'id' => 2,
                                        'name' => 'SubCategory1',
                                        'parent' => 1,
                                        'children' => array
                                            (
                                                '0' => array
                                                    (
                                                        'id' => 3,
                                                        'name' => 'SubSubCategory',
                                                        'parent' => 2,
                                                        'children' => array
                                                            (
                                                            )

                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )
                );      
$select_str = '<select>';
foreach($your_array as $val)
{
    $select_str .= '<option value="'.$val['id'].'" parent ="'.$val['parent'].'">'.$val['name'].'</option>';
    if(is_array($val['children']))
    {
        $select_str .= implemt_recur($val['children']);
    }
}
$select_str .= '</select>';
echo $select_str;
// implement recursion and make options here
function implemt_recur($array)
{
    $sub_select_str = '';
    if(!empty($array))
    {
        foreach($array as $arr)
        {
            $sub_select_str .= '<option value="'.$arr['id'].'" parent ="'.$arr['parent'].'">'.$arr['name'].'</option>';
            if(is_array($arr['children']))
            {
                $sub_select_str .= implemt_recur($arr['children']);
            }
        }
    }   
    return $sub_select_str;
}
?>
```